# ReferenceError: indexproduct is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm getting reference error in every route like: "/","/product" even though that variable is not used on those routes.Although pages load fine with no errors in front but it shows error in terminal .Please help it i'm trying to figure out for days and not able to continue with my project

app.js:`

```
 app.get("/", function(req, res){//landing page
      product.find({},function(error,indexproduct){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }else{
          res.render("index",{indexproduct:indexproduct});
        }
      });

    });`
```

index.ejs:

```
    <% include partials/header %>
      <!-- Start slider -->
      <section id="aa-slider">
        <div class="aa-slider-area">
          <div id="sequence" class="seq">
            <div class="seq-screen">
              <ul class="seq-canvas">
                <!-- single slide item -->
                <li>
                  <div class="seq-model">
                    <img data-seq src="/img/slide8.jpg" alt="Men slide img" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="seq-title">
                   <span data-seq>Save Up to 75% Off</span>
                    <h2 data-seq>Men Collection</h2>
                    <p data-seq>Best Place to Buy Awesome Men's Clothing</p>
                    <a data-seq href="/category/men" class="aa-shop-now-btn aa-secondary-btn">SHOP NOW</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!-- single slide item -->
                <li>
                  <div class="seq-model">
                    <img data-seq src="/img/slide10.jpg" alt="Wristwatch slide img" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="seq-title">
                    <span data-seq>Save Up to 40% Off</span>
                    <h2 data-seq>Kids Clothing Collection</h2>
                    <p data-seq>Style your Kid's with latest Trends</p>
                    <a data-seq href="/category/kid" class="aa-shop-now-btn aa-secondary-btn">SHOP NOW</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!-- single slide item -->
                <li>
                  <div class="seq-model">
                    <img data-seq src="/img/slide4.jpg" alt="Women Jeans slide img" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="seq-title">
                    <span data-seq>Save Up to 75% Off</span>
                    <h2 data-seq>Women Dress Collection</h2>
                    <p data-seq>Style your Own Life with our trendy cloths</p>
                    <a data-seq href="/category/women" class="aa-shop-now-btn aa-secondary-btn">SHOP NOW</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!-- single slide item -->
                <!-- single slide item -->
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- slider navigation btn -->
            <fieldset class="seq-nav" aria-controls="sequence" aria-label="Slider buttons">
              <a type="button" class="seq-prev" aria-label="Previous"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span></a>
              <a type="button" class="seq-next" aria-label="Next"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- / slider -->
      <!-- Start Promo section -->
      <section id="aa-promo">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="aa-promo-area">
                <div class="row">
                  <!-- promo left -->
                  <div class="col-md-5 no-padding">
                    <div class="aa-promo-left">
                      <div class="aa-promo-banner">
                        <img src="/img/slide5.jpg" alt="img">
                        <div class="aa-prom-content">
                          <span>75% Off</span>
                          <h4><a href="/category/women">For Women</a></h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- promo right -->
                  <div class="col-md-7 no-padding">
                    <div class="aa-promo-right">
                      <div class="aa-single-promo-right">
                        <div class="aa-promo-banner">
                          <img src="/img/slide6.jpg" alt="img">
                          <div class="aa-prom-content">
                            <span>Exclusive Item</span>
                            <h4><a href="/category/men.jpg">For Men</a></h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="aa-single-promo-right">
                        <div class="aa-promo-banner">
                          <img src="/img/slide3.jpg" alt="img">
                          <div class="aa-prom-content">
                            <span>Sale Off</span>
                            <h4><a href="/category/women">On Every Ladies Dress</a></h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="aa-single-promo-right">
                        <div class="aa-promo-banner">
                          <img src="/img/slide9.jpg" alt="img">
                          <div class="aa-prom-content">
                            <span>New Arrivals</span>
                            <h4><a href="/category/kid">For Kids</a></h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="aa-single-promo-right">
                        <div class="aa-promo-banner">
                          <img src="/img/slide1.jpg" alt="img">
                          <div class="aa-prom-content">
                            <span>25% Off</span>
                            <h4><a href="/category/men">For Men's Clothing</a></h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- / Promo section -->

      <!-- banner section -->
      <section id="aa-banner">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="aa-banner-area">
                <a href="/category/men"><img src="/img/slide2.jpg" alt="fashion banner img"></a>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- popular section -->
      <section id="aa-popular-category">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="aa-popular-category-area">
                  <!-- start prduct navigation -->
                 <ul class="nav nav-tabs aa-products-tab">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#popular" data-toggle="tab">Exclusive</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <!-- Tab panes -->
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <!-- Start men popular category -->
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="popular">
                      <ul class="aa-product-catg aa-popular-slider">
                        <!-- start single product item -->
    <%=console.log(indexproduct)%>
                      </ul>
                      <a class="aa-browse-btn" href="/product">Browse all Product <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- / popular product category -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- / popular section -->
      <!-- Support section -->
      <section id="aa-support">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="aa-support-area">
                <!-- single support -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="aa-support-single">
                    <span class="fa fa-truck"></span>
                    <h4>FREE SHIPPING</h4>
                    <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, nobis.</P>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- single support -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="aa-support-single">
                    <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
                    <h4>30 DAYS MONEY BACK</h4>
                    <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, nobis.</P>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- single support -->
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="aa-support-single">
                    <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                    <h4>SUPPORT 24/7</h4>
                    <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, nobis.</P>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- / Support section -->
    <% include partials/footer %>`
```

Error:

```
`ReferenceError: C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\views\index.ejs:156
    154|                   <ul class="aa-product-catg aa-popular-slider">
    155|                     <!-- start single product item -->
 >> 156| <%=console.log(indexproduct)%>
    157|                   </ul>
    158|                   <a class="aa-browse-btn" href="/product">Browse all Product <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></span></a>
    159|                 </div>

indexproduct is not defined
    at eval (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\views\index.ejs:74:37)
    at index (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:682:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\app.js:396:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\Users\nishantk\Desktop\project200\renclo\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
```

`

Comment: If you `console.log('indexproduct:', indexproduct)` before doing `res.render`, does it show in the console?

Comment: and does you partials work correctly? in front-end?